# Printing with the System.WIndows.Forms.WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

I'm using th WebBrowser control in the .net 2.0 framework. Is it possible to change the printing behavior so it always prints to the default printer, without showing any dialog to the user?  This is for a kiosk so there will always be a printer directly connected to the Kiosk, and printing should be seemless to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the default PrinterName using the method shown here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-[us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.isdefaultprinter.aspx](http://us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.isdefaultprinter.aspx)

and then pass that name to the PrinterSettings property of the PrintDocument.

Comment: I'm not sure how it will change the behavior of print functionality withing the WebBrowser control.  If the user clicks on a print butto in the webbrowser control, they will still get a print dialog

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the WebBroser.Print() method.
I've used it before and it directly prints to the default printer.