# C#: Printing a Report

Tags: c#, printing

How can I add regular printing functionality to my application so that I can create a custom report (say, in an RTF format) to print? Also, is it somehow possible to combine print preview with this?

**UPDATE:** Oh and also, what is built-in in the .NET Framework in terms of printing?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the ReportViewer that is shipped with Visual Studio. It covers both Windows Forms and Web Forms.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will open yourself up to a world of pain here, and this problem has been solved before.

What are you trying to print?  I'll assume you have a win-forms application.

When you say custom, do you mean the user will be entering the rtf or html code themselves (either manually, or with an editor such as [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) or [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/))

You could drop in an Internet Explorer control, and invoke a print from there.  Or there are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610183/printing-webbrowser-control-content) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219234/printing-with-the-system-windows-forms-webbrowser-control) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990/printing-from-a-net-service) options.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some commercial packages like the [Xtra Reports suite](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/) from DevExpress

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a 3rd party as Pratik mentioned, Active reports is quite simple, or if need a more robust can use SSRS.